# How can I add the value of a button to a textarea when clicking the button?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a textarea, in which user can write a comment. To make their life easy I also have set of buttons which basically have predefined value. These are quick comments button that can be clicked and it should add the value of button to the textarea. Its almost like StackOverflow's tags search box where you can type to add the tags or you can select the suggested tags by SO, that are outside the search box on the bottom.

If I am able to render/added the comments value on text area with the existing text in the text area that would solve my problem i think. thank you

Picture of what the UI component looks like : 
[image: quick comments and text area]

The `savePatientComment()` is how I save the value of the textArea.

savePatientComment( { target: { name, value } }, data, index ){

```
    this.setState({

        patientInfo: this.state.patientInfo.map((patient, i) => {
            if (i === index) {
                return { ...patient, [name]: value };
            }
            return patient;
        }),
    });

}
```

Patient Row component

```
  <div>
     <Button value="quick comments-1" onClick={//add the value to text area}>Quick comments</Button>
     <Button value="quick comments-2" onClick={//add the value to text area}>Quick comments</Button>
     <Button value="quick comments-3" onClick={//add the value to text area}>Quick comments</Button>

  </div>
  <textarea
           className="patient-comment-textarea"
           placeholder="type your comments here"
           name="comment"
           value={patient.comment}
           onChange={(e) => savePatientComment(e, patient, index)} >
  </textarea>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Errors: Use array of comments and iterate to display `<button />`. onClick update state for valueArr. 
Also, `onChange` and `value` property on  for displaying comments data.

This is working solution.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    valueArr: []
  };
  changeHandler = event => {
    this.setState({ valueArr: [event.target.value] });
  };
  clickHandler = datum => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({ valueArr: [...prevState.valueArr, datum] }));
  };
  render() {
    const comments = ["working", "sleeping", "eating", "coding"];
    return (
      <div>
        {comments.map(datum => (
          <button
            className="comment-btn"
            onClick={() => this.clickHandler(datum)}
          >
            {datum}
          </button>
        ))}
        <br />
        <textarea
          rows="6"
          cols="30"
          value={this.state.valueArr}
          onChange={event => this.changeHandler(event)}
          placeholder="type your comment here"
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
.comment-btn {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: solid 1px greenyellow;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>
```

Comment: Hi @AvinashMahlawat thank you for your pro answer. I've managed to make it work on my app. I would like to confirm my understanding if that's okay.

Is your clickHandler taking in the comment button value as datum and spreading the previous state valueArr to add datum which is what is being passed from clickHandler()?

Answer (score 0):

This should get you on the right track

```
<script>

function addNewComment(e){
  var content = $('#comment').val();
  content = content + '. ' + $(e).val();

}


</script>

<div>
   <Button value="I'll call you later" onClick='addNewComment(this)'>Quick comments</Button>
   <Button value="I'm in a meeting" onClick='addNewComment(this)'>Quick comments</Button>
   <Button value="I need some water" onClick='addNewComment(this)'>Quick comments</Button>

</div>
<textarea
         className="patient-comment-textarea"
         id="comment"
         placeholder="type your comments here"
         name="comment"
         value={patient.comment}
         onChange={(e) => savePatientComment(e, patient, index)} >
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my how I would do it.

```
 <body>

  <div>
    <input type="button" name="" value="Hello"></input>
    <input type="button" name="" value="Good Job"></input>
    <input type="button" name="" value="Have a nice day"></input>
  </div>

  <!-- A form for sending/ saving data  -->
  <form class="" method="post">
    <textarea rows="4" cols="50">this is you current text</textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="" value="submit">
  </form>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    const buttons = document.querySelector('div') // Selecting all the buttons
    const form = document.querySelector('form textarea') // Selecting my textarea

    buttons.addEventListener('click', e => {
      // when a button is clicked add the value to the textarea
      form.value += ' ' + e.target.value
      console.log(form.value, e.target.value);
    })
  </script>
</body>
```

Hope it was Helpful ^_^